# Cannot configure Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5.7

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, ibm-was

I'm trying to configure **Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5.7** with **Eclipse Mars** but when I start it I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0002E: A bundle could not be found for com.ibm.ws.javaee.el.2.2/[1.0.0,1.0.100).
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0002E: A bundle could not be found for com.ibm.ws.javaee.jsp.2.2/[1.0.0,1.0.100).
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0002E: A bundle could not be found for com.ibm.ws.org.apache.jasper.el.2.2/[1.0.0,1.0.100).
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0002E: A bundle could not be found for com.ibm.ws.org.eclipse.jdt.core.3.10.0.v20140902-0626/[1.0.0,1.0.100).
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0002E: A bundle could not be found for com.ibm.ws.jsp.factories.2.2/[1.0.0,1.0.100).
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0002E: A bundle could not be found for com.ibm.ws.javaee.jstl.1.2/[1.0.0,1.0.100).
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0002E: A bundle could not be found for com.ibm.ws.jsp-2.2org.apache.jasper/[1.0.0,1.0.100).
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0002E: A bundle could not be found for com.ibm.ws.jsp/[1.0.0,1.0.100).
```

There is my `server.xml` file:

```
<server description="new server">
    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="{xor}12345"/> 
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  host="localhost"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" />

</server>
```

Also I've tried to install optional feature **jaxrs-2.0**, I've installed it from bin\featureManager utility but when I add it to `server.xml` I get warning `This feature 'jaxrs-2.0' is not recognized`.

What may I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been a few similar reports. Usually a Clean server restart will fix it. From the tools right click on the server in the server view. Click on the clean server on next start and then restart the server. In general this clears the problem. We are looking into it.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding installing the jaxrs-2.0 feature, if you install through the command line then the tools do not know about it.  You can refresh the runtime information cached by the tools by doing the following:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environment -> SELECT YOUR RUNTIME -> CLICK Edit -> CLICK Advanced options... -> CLICK Refresh
```

Wait for the timestamp to be updated then right click on the server.xml in the explorer view and select **Validate**.

If you install features through the tools then the cached information will be updated automatically.  To install through the tools open the **Runtime Explorer** view, right click on the runtime and select **Install Additional Content**.